# Filter with association : SQL error no such column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, search, associations

I m trying to implant filter after query. I have 2 models with association 1) Camping 2)Caracteristiquetest. Modele Caracteristiquetest have camping_id. Query works but when i m trying to apply filter with checkbox i have an error. I think it's an association problem.

How I can fix that ? Thanks for your help.

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: handicap: SELECT "campings".*
>   FROM "campings" WHERE (piscine LIKE '%%' AND barbecue LIKE '%%' AND
>   nomdep LIKE '%aube%' AND handicap LIKE '%oui%')

### MODEL

**Camping.rb**

```
  scope :handicap, -> (handicap) { where handicap: "oui" }
belongs_to :caracteristiquetest

def self.search(piscine, barbecue, nomdep, handicap)
   return scoped unless piscine.present? || barbecue.present? || nomdep.present? || handicap.present?
  where(['piscine LIKE ? AND barbecue LIKE ? AND nomdep LIKE ? AND handicap LIKE ?', "%#{piscine}%", "%#{barbecue}%", "%#{nomdep}%", "%#{handicap}%"])
end
```

**Caracteristiquetst.rb**

```
has_one :camping
```

### CONTROLLER

**camping_controller.rb**

```
      def resultnohome
        if params[:piscine] && params[:barbecue] && params[:nomdep] && params[:handicap].blank?
          redirect_to action: :index and return
        else
          @campings = Camping.search(params[:piscine], params[:barbecue], params[:nomdep], params[:handicap])
        end

end
```

### VIEW

**_searchfilter.html.erb**

```
<%= text_field_tag :nomdep, params[:nomdep], class:"SearchFilter", placeholder:"Ex : Vendée, Corse..." %>

<li><p><span class="IcoSwim" aria-hidden="true"></span> Piscine : <%= check_box_tag :piscine, "oui", !!params[:piscine], :class => "piscine" %></p></li>
<li><p><span class="IcoSlide" aria-hidden="true"></span>Toboggan aquatique </p></li>
<li><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire" aria-hidden="true"></span> Barbecue : <%= check_box_tag :barbecue, "oui", !!params[:barbecue], :class => "barbecue" %></p></li>
<li><p><span class="IcoHandi" aria-hidden="true"></span> Accès handicapé : <%= check_box_tag :handicap, "oui", !!params[:handicap], :class => "handicap" %></p></li>
<%= submit_tag "Appliquer les filtres", class:"btn btn-danger2", name: nil %>
```

### EDIT

Some precisions : Filter by piscine or barbecue works because they are on same migration, same model but filtring by handicap doesnt work.

Structure of camping table

```
class CreateCampings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :campings do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :adresse
      t.string :code_postale
      t.string :commune
      t.string :courriel
      t.string :site_internet
      t.string :tel
      t.text :description
      t.string :nomdep
      t.string :nomregion
      t.string :numdep
      t.string :slug
      t.integer :ville_id
      t.integer :region_id
      t.integer :departement_id
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude
      t.string :etoile
      t.string :piscine
      t.string :barbecue
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :caracteristiquetest_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Table structure of caracteristiquetest

```
class CreateCaracteristiquetests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :caracteristiquetests do |t|
      t.string :handicap
      t.integer :camping_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

### EDIT2

After some searches on google I think .joins to join two tables can be the solution. So I made this on my camping.rb

```
def self.searchi(nomdep, handicap)
   return scoped unless nomdep.present?
joins(:caracteristiquetest).where(['nomdep LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? AND handicap LIKE ?', "%#{nomdep}%", "%#{nomdep}%", "%#{handicap}%"])

end
```

But, now i have another error...

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: campings.camping_id: SELECT
>   "campings".* FROM "campings" INNER JOIN "caracteristiquetests" ON
>   "caracteristiquetests"."id" = "campings"."camping_id" WHERE (nomdep
>   LIKE '%camping%' OR name LIKE '%camping%' AND handicap LIKE '%%')

What is the method to fix that ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `handicap` field in your table structure. So the error message is self-explanatory.

Comment: Handicap field is in caracteristiquetest table in my edit                      class CreateCaracteristiquetests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :caracteristiquetests do |t|
      t.string :handicap
      t.integer :camping_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get result from camping and handicap is a column of caracteristiquetests .
Add a field 'handicap' IN camping .

```
rails g migration addHandicapToCamping handicap
```

Comment: Yes.  But i dont want to add column on camping db. I want search with association

Comment: so you'll have to -join-  that extra table to your query  before -select- inside the group created.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, problem was on association.

Camping.rb

```
has_many :caracteristiquetests
```

Caracteristiquetest.rb

```
belongs_to :camping
```

After i add this on my model and i can filter with params from another table. `left_outer_joins(:caracteristiquetests).where(mywhere)`